# Spacing after redefining maketitle

Tags: spacing, titles, article

I have trouble obtaining the needed space after redefining `\maketitle` in the article class. I do not want the spacing after the title to depend on whether I start with `\section` or not.

For instance,

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\@maketitle{\Huge\textbf{New Title}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

    \maketitle

    Some text
\end{document}
```

yields a much smaller space after the title than

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\@maketitle{\Huge\textbf{New Title}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

    \maketitle

    \section{Some section}

    Some text
\end{document}
```

I understand why this is the case, and it is trivial to add the needed space manually, but I am wondering if LaTeX can do it for me.

Comment: You can add the desired skip as part of the definition, as in`\def\@maketitle{\Huge\textbf{New Title}\bigskip}`.  `\section` adds its own pre-skip in your 2nd example.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes It seems like there will then be two `\bigskip` when using `\section`, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, `\section` will always adds its own space, in addition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on OP comments, it seems that it is desired to make the vertical space conditional, only adding it if there is not additional vertical space added by another following command, for example, `\section`.

In this case, you are looking for `\addvspace`, which must be invoked in vertical mode.  Thus, adding `\par\addvspace{<length>}` to the end of your revised `\maketitle` will only add this space if is not already being added by what follows.

In the MWE, you can comment and uncomment the `\section` command to see the result.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\@maketitle{\Huge\textbf{New Title}\par\addvspace{15pt}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

    \maketitle

%\section{Title}
    Some text
\end{document}
```

With no following `\section`:

[image]

With following `\section`:

[image]